# How can I add a userID as uniqueidentifier data type in stored procedure?

Tags: sql-server

I created a stored procedure but when I tried to use it I got error.

> "Msg 8114, Level 16, State 5, Procedure SP_Customer_Add, Line 0 [Batch
>   Start Line 36] Error converting data type varchar to
>   uniqueidentifier."

```
alter proc SP_Customer_Add (
    @UserID uniqueidentifier,
    @Firstname nvarchar(30),
    @Surname nvarchar(30),
    @CardNumber nvarchar(16),
    @Password nvarchar(4),
    @City nvarchar(13), 
    @Birthdate smalldatetime,
    @Email nvarchar(30), 
    @PhoneNumber nvarchar (10),
    @Balance money 
)
as 
begin 
    set nocount on;
    insert into Customers (
        [UserID],
        [Firstname], 
        [Surname], 
        [CardNumber], 
        [Password], 
        [City], 
        [Birthdate], 
        [Email], 
        [PhoneNumber], 
        [Balance] 
    ) values (
        @UserID,
        @Firstname,
        @Surname,
        @CardNumber,
        @Password,
        @City, 
        @Birthdate,
        @Email , 
        @PhoneNumber ,
        @Balance
    )
    select @UserID  = newID();
END
```

I call the procedure like:

```
exec SP_Customer_Add 

    'Cem',
    'Yücel',
    '1234567891234567',
    '1111','Malatya',
    '1999/12/5',
    'Cemyucel@yahoo.com',
    '5421234312',
    10000
```

Comment: Hello @Barış Tunar, can you please share with us what database do you use? Oracle, MySQL or something else ? Thanks!

Comment: I'm using SQL  .

Comment: Hi @Barış Tunar, that is not correct. That is a language(Structured Query Language). I think you are using SQL Server.

Comment: Yes. SQL Server. I'm sorry. I am newbie ^^

Comment: Careful, `sp_` is reserved by Microsoft and means **Special** Procedure (not Stored Procedure). Using the `sp_` prefix had a negative effect on performance and your Stored Procedure could suddenly stop working if a Special Procedure with that name is made. [Is the sp_ prefix still a no-no?](https://sqlperformance.com/2012/10/t-sql-queries/sp_prefix)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're inserting rows with a GUID, then let the RDBMS handle the generation. I *assume* that the ID is also the `CLUSTERED INDEX` so change it so that it has a default value:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Customers ADD CONSTRAINT DF_UserID DEFAULT NEWSEQUENTIALID() FOR UserID;
```

Then `DROP` your SP and recreate it with the name `Customer_Add` (because having the prefix is a problem, as my comment says) and recreate the SP without any references to `UserID` as a variable or to `INSERT`.

Answer (score 1):

Your are not passing a value for the parameter (@UserID) when calling the procedure SP_Customer_Add

```
exec SP_Customer_Add 

'Cem', 
'Yücel', 
'1234567891234567', 
'1111','Malatya',
'1999/12/5',
'Cemyucel@yahoo.com',
'5421234312',
10000
```

Below is the altered procedure:

```
alter proc SP_Customer_Add
(
@Firstname nvarchar(30),
@Surname nvarchar(30),
@CardNumber nvarchar(16),
@Password nvarchar(4),
@City nvarchar(13), 
@Birthdate smalldatetime,
@Email nvarchar(30), 
@PhoneNumber nvarchar (10),
@Balance money 
)
as 
begin 
set nocount on;

DECLARE @UserID uniqueidentifier

SET @UserID = NEWID()

insert into Customers ([UserID],[Firstname], [Surname], [CardNumber], [Password], [City], [Birthdate], [Email], [PhoneNumber], [Balance] )
values
(
@UserID,
@Firstname,
@Surname,
@CardNumber,
@Password,
@City, 
@Birthdate,
@Email , 
@PhoneNumber ,
@Balance
)

END
```

Comment: Although this tells the OP why they are getting the error, it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: (UserID) is a Primary Key.  What I need to do?

Comment: Hopefully, with this solution, `UserID` isn't your `CLUSTERED INDEX` @BarışTunar .